# How to describe $\sec^{-1}{x}$ in terms of $\tan^{-1}{x}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

How to describe $\sec^{-1}{x}$ in terms of $\tan^{-1}{x}$?

I tried the following:
$y=\sec^{-1}{x}\Longleftrightarrow x=\sec{y}$

$x^2=\tan^2{y}+1$

$\tan{y}=\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}$

$\sec^{-1}{x}=\tan^{-1}({\pm\sqrt{x^2-1})}$

$\sec^{-1}{x} =
\begin{cases}
\tan^{-1}({\sqrt{x^2-1})},  & \text{if $x\ge1$} \\
\color{red}{\tan^{-1}({-\sqrt{x^2-1})}}, & \text{if $x\le-1$}
\end{cases}$

However, the part in red apparently isn't right. It should be:

$\sec^{-1}{x}=\pi-\tan^{-1}({\sqrt{x^2-1})}$ if $x\le-1$

QUESTION 1: What is wrong with my method?

QUESTION 2: How to arrive at the right answer?

Comment: The title suggests that you are seeking a relationship between $\text{arcsec}(x)$ and $\arctan(x)$, not $\text{arcsec}(x)$ and $\arctan(y)$.  Quite different.

Comment: @Dr.MV I introduced y as an intermediate step. As a final result still arcsec(x) is desribed in terms of arctan(x)

Comment: No it isn't.  The argument under the arctangent function is not $x$.  Instead you wrote $\text{arcsec}(x)=\arctan(f(x)$.  This is in contrast to, say the expression, $\text{arcsec}(x)=\arccos(\cot(\arctan(x)))$ which expresses the arcsecant as a function of arctangent.

Answer (score 1):

when you write $y=\sec^{-1} x$ you are implicitly defining $y\in [0,\pi]-\{\pi/2\}$
so when you write $$\tan y=\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}$$$$y=\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}$$
you are violating domain of $y$

**How to arrive at correct step**

Now since  $\tan y=-\sqrt{x^2-1}$ and $\tan y$ is negative $y$ should fall in 2nd or fourth quadrant. Since fourth quadrant is not in domain so $\tan y$ can lie only in 2nd quadrant . Now the difference between fourth and the 2nd quadrant is of$\pi$ you can add $\pi$ and $\tan y$ will also remain unchanged. and $y$ will fall in its domain $\forall x$

Answer (score 0):

The range of the arctangent function is $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$, but the range of the arcsecant function is $[0,\pi] - \{\pi/2\}$. Angles differing by $\pi$ have the same tangent value, so you can translate angles from quadrant 4 to quadrant 2 by adding $\pi$, not changing the tangent, and moving into the range of arcsecant.

Comment: What is the solution to $\sec^{-1} t = \frac \pi 2$?

Comment: Good catch. I've fixed that. :)

Comment: The range is not $(0,\pi)$; it is $[0,\pi/2)\,U\,(\pi/2,\pi]$